# How to Fix Cakephp 4 Composer Install Error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Having issues installing all packages for cakephp 4.0 via Composer. Running a fresh wamp server install on Windows with PHP 7.4.0

Here is composer output. Using the command found in the cakephp docs.

```
www/> composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:^4.0 myapp
Installing cakephp/app (4.0.0)
  - Installing cakephp/app (4.0.0): Loading from cache
Created project in kollectit
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package cakephp/bake ^4.0 exists as cakephp/bake[0.1.0, 0.1.10, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13, 1.0.14, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.12.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.10, 1.2.11, 1.2.12, 1.2.13, 1.2.14, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2.8, 1.2.9, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.x-dev, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, dev-3.next, dev-dereuromark-patch-1, dev-fix-old-alias, dev-master, dev-twigview-5] but these are rejected by your constraint.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for cakephp/migrations 3.0.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by cakephp/migrations[3.0.0-beta1].
    - cakephp/migrations 3.0.0-beta1 requires robmorgan/phinx 0.11.x-dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

The base cakephp installation is there in the /myapp folder, but wondering on the errors and if they are needed (if so how to resolve? )

Here is the composer.json that is created:

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/app",
    "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
    "homepage": "https://cakephp.org",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "^4.0",
        "cakephp/migrations": "3.0.0-beta1",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.0",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "cakephp/bake": "^4.0",
        "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "dev-next",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "^4.0",
        "josegonzalez/dotenv": "3.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
        "psy/psysh": "@stable"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "markstory/asset_compress": "An asset compression plugin which provides file concatenation and a flexible filter system for preprocessing and minification.",
        "dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper": "After baking your code, this keeps your annotations in sync with the code evolving from there on for maximum IDE and PHPStan/Psalm compatibility."
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Test\\": "tests/",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
        "post-create-project-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Cake\\Composer\\Installer\\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump",
        "check": [
            "@test",
            "@cs-check"
        ],
        "cs-check": "phpcs --colors -p --standard=vendor/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/CakePHP src/ tests/",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf --colors --standard=vendor/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/CakePHP src/ tests/",
        "stan": "phpstan analyse src/",
        "stan-setup": "cp composer.json composer.backup && composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan-shim:^0.11 && mv composer.backup composer.json",
        "test": "phpunit --colors=always"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the latest app template (`4.0.2` currently), there have been some fixes around this.

The problem is that you are using `^` on the Windows command line, where the caret character is an escape character, ie it's not being passed to composer, which will only receive `cakephp/app:4.0`, which means that it will install `4.0.0`.

Simple fix, enclose the package argument in double quotes:

```sh
composer create-project --prefer-dist "cakephp/app:^4.0" myapp
```

or do not specify a version constraint at all, which will automatically give you the latest stable version:

```sh
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app myapp
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! something simple of course... installed w/o issue using 2nd (and pulled down 4.0.2)