# cant install cakephp 4 again

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I have wamp64, php 7.4 and using composer I ran this from the console

composer create-project --prefer-dist "cakephp/app:^4.0" myapp

and

composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:~4.0 my_app_name

The installation cut out towards the end with this error

```
Script App\Console\Installer::postInstall handing the post create project cmd event terminated with an exception 

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RunTimeException\ Aborted
and some Symfony runtime exception when you get to the set folder permission y/n
```

It created this JSON file

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/app",
    "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
    "homepage": "https://cakephp.org",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "~4.2.0",
        "cakephp/migrations": "^3.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.3",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "cakephp/bake": "^2.3",
        "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "~4.2.0",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "^4.4",
        "josegonzalez/dotenv": "^3.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~8.5.0 || ^9.3",
        "psy/psysh": "@stable"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "markstory/asset_compress": "An asset compression plugin which provides file concatenation and a flexible filter system for preprocessing and minification.",
        "dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper": "After baking your code, this keeps your annotations in sync with the code evolving from there on for maximum IDE and PHPStan/Psalm compatibility.",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "PHPStan focuses on finding errors in your code without actually running it. It catches whole classes of bugs even before you write tests for the code."
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Test\\": "tests/",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
        "post-create-project-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
        "check": [
            "@test",
            "@cs-check"
        ],
        "cs-check": "phpcs --colors -p  src/ tests/",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf --colors -p src/ tests/",
        "stan": "phpstan analyse",
        "test": "phpunit --colors=always"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

[How to Fix Cakephp 4 Composer Install Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548704/how-to-fix-cakephp-4-composer-install-error)

(i didnt understand the solution to this)
[Cakephp 4 Windows Installation Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61196192/cakephp-4-windows-installation-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to get it to work. What Windows version do you use? Pro or Home? Which distribution? 2010?
Please make sure to navigate to the WAMP install folder and then specifically the www folder.
The command I use is this;

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:~4.0 cake
```

It worked for me.
Alternatively, download Cakephp version 4.0, place the contents in the www folder, and configure it manually through the file /config/app.php. If you want, we can look at it together. There are not many people around me that can or want to work on Cakephp, so it'd be a pleasure. :)